# How filter a GET parameter for a specific URL in IIS 10?

Tags: iis

I have an openredirect vulnerability on my web application. You can learn about this with the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340714/azure-ad-b2c-vulnerable-to-open-redirect

Because it is a problem with a Microsoft product, it is not possible to fix this.

So I'm wondering if it is possible with IIS, to filter a GET parameter for a specific URL.

I just want to authorize one URL in the post_logout_redirect_uri GET parameters.

Comment: What language are you using backend?

Comment: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) is probably a better site for this. I'm not sure if it's off-topic _here_, but if you don't get answers over the next few days, you should delete this question and post it there.